# Android Eclipse App not working correctly in foreign language with database

Tags: android, database, eclipse, textview

I've released an app, and I recently found out that its not working 100% correctly in a foreign language (French to be exact).

It appears it works correctly until I create a cursor from a database and manipulate my returned data.  I have text views that either gray out with default text, or it populates with what is returned from the cursor.  What is happening is that it is doing neither of those things, and instead just uses the text that is in the layout I created.

Here is the code:

Cursor item = mDbHelper.fetchItem(mItemId);

```
String airline =item.getString(
                    item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_FIELD_FLIGHT_AIRLINE));

TextView itemAirline = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.flight_item_airline);
            if(airline==null||airline.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){

                itemAirline.setText(R.string.default_carrier);
                itemAirline.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_orange));
            }else{
            itemAirline.setText(item.getString(
                    item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_FIELD_FLIGHT_AIRLINE)));
                    //itemAirline.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
```

As you can see, I do a check to see if the database item called is null or "null" and change the text view accordingly.  It doesn't appear to be getting to that though since it doesn't change at all.  Keep in mind this has always worked perfectly when run on an English Language phone.  The rest of my app seems to run fine in French as well except for this feature.

Here is my Database call too in case it is needed:

```
public Cursor fetchItem(long itemId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor =
                mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_ITEMS, COLUMNS, KEY_ITEMID + "=" + itemId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I am getting a LogCat message of an unparseable date when I switch my phone to the French Language.  The code that parses the date is:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);

String itemDate = item.getString(
                    item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_DEP_DATE));
            System.out.println("Before PArse Dates");
            Date dateObj = df.parse(itemDate);
```

The date in question is of format Month, day, year.  So I know where the problem is happening, but I still can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the unparseable date exception I was getting was just from incorrect formatting, and that my code was just stopping on the exception which is what caused my original problem.

For future reference, if you want to parse something like "2012-10-05":

```
private static final String DATE_SQL = "yyyy-MM-dd";
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "MMM dd, yyyy";

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_SQL, Utility.getLocale());
Date dateObj = df.parse("2012-10-05");

//Format it to a more user friendly date
System.out.println(sdf.format(dateObj));   //Oct. 05, 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas, might not be related:

1. why `airline.equalsIgnoreCase("null")`?
   don't see any reason for it to be "null" (the string), should be `airline.isEmpty()`.
2. you should change the

`if (mCursor != null) {`

into

`if ((mCursor != null) && (mCursor.getCount() != 0)) {`

While you debug what is the value of airline? (when the language is french)
check the log cat, it really sound like you have an exception somewhere there and that's why the if "is not working"

the second thing, seems very reasonable... (you'r query returned 0 records and you are trying to move to the first one...)

edit:
from the comments, so it will be easier to read:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String locale = prefs.getString(Preferences.KEY_LOCALE, "null");
return locale;
```

will get the the locale (for example, fr_FR in case it's french (if i'm not worng..))

Comment: Thanks for recommendations.  I will update my code to use these best practices, but I think I found where the problem is occurring and have updated my original question.. still no solution though

Comment: try using the locale: DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.FRANCE);

Comment: That will work, but how would one go about being able to dynamically switch the Locale?  If I have users from 20 different countries, is there some way to make it dynamic\?

Comment: you can get the locale like this SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String locale = prefs.getString(Preferences.KEY_LOCALE, "null");
return locale;

Comment: That code gives the following error: KEY_LOCALE cannot be resolved or is not a field.  Are you sure that is the correct syntax?

Comment: it's an example. i'm assuming you are using the preferences screen to let the user set the locale (there for the PreferenceManager) and there you have a key field for the locale, named KEY_LOCALE... you need to make adjustments to the code so it will work in your case.